# Curl can't follow "This page should automatically redirect"

Tags: shell-script, redirection, curl

I'm attempting to automate a login for the a course webpage I have to check this semester. I know that the POST request I am making is being done correctly because I get to the intermediate redirect page that you only get on a successful login.

I'm basically hitting one of those `This page should automatically redirect. If nothing is happening please use the continue link below.` pages. Unfortunately because curl isn't following this final redirect, it doesn't seem to be setting the last cookies to keep my session.

I've been reading the `man` for curl, but I can't seem to find the correct way to get this done (`--max-time` and `--max-redirs` are what I've tried and aren't working).

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to resolve this?

Here's what' I'm working with

```
LOGINURL="http://www.[redacted].edu/login/index.php" # This is not https because they don't support it.
COURSEURL="http://www.[redacted].edu/course/[redacted]"
USERAGENT="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0"
COOKIEJAR="${HOME}/edu.cookies"
POSTDATA="[redacted]"
curl -o "index.html" --referer "${LOGINURL}" --user-agent "${USERAGENT}" --cookie-jar "${COOKIEJAR}" --data "${POSTDATA}" "${LOGINURL}"
curl -o "course.html" --referer "${LOGINURL}" --user-agent "${USERAGENT}" --cookie "${COOKIEJAR}" "${COURSEURL}"
```

PS, the link that is provided on the intermediate redirect page is the same link as the COURSEURL url, so manually curling it does not work.

Comment: Do you know what kind of redirect they're using?  Javascript?  Server side?  META refresh?

Comment: @ernie I just barely saw your comment, it's a server-side redirect. The page's source doesn't have any Javascript or have a Meta-Refresh. It turns out all curl needed was `-L`.

Answer (score 0):

I feel absolutely silly. The `-L` option was all I needed.
From the man page:

```
-L, --location
              (HTTP/HTTPS)  If  the  server reports that the requested page has moved to a different location (indicated with a Location: header and a 3XX response code),
              this option will make curl redo the request on the new place. If used together with -i, --include or -I, --head, headers from all requested  pages  will  be
              shown.  When  authentication is used, curl only sends its credentials to the initial host. If a redirect takes curl to a different host, it won't be able to
              intercept the user+password. See also --location-trusted on how to change this. You can limit the amount of redirects to follow by  using  the  --max-redirs
              option.

              When  curl follows a redirect and the request is not a plain GET (for example POST or PUT), it will do the following request with a GET if the HTTP response
              was 301, 302, or 303. If the response code was any other 3xx code, curl will re-send the following request using the same unmodified method.
```